# Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Server::executeReadCommand()

Tags: php, mongodb, composer-php, php-7

Our application is running on a (very) old MongoDB 2.4 cluster - for now, it's not possible to upgrade it to newer versions.

We were working on upgrading our application from PHP 5.6 to PHP7, everything was going fine until [the version 1.4.0 of the mongodb driver deprecated MongoDB 2.4 support](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases/tag/1.4.0).

Since we need to support `2.4`, I tried to rollback the driver version to `1.3.0` and `1.3.2` and both of them are throwing this error:

`Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Server::executeReadCommand()`

This `executeReadCommand()` seems to be something from `1.4.0`, but how can that be if I'm using the version `1.3.0`? Am I missing something?

PHP Configuration:

```
PHP 7.1.12 (cli) (built: Dec  1 2017 01:55:23) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.12, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

Mongo Driver Configuration:

```
root@6f40fb118d2d:/var/www/app# php --ri mongodb | grep version
MongoDB extension version => 1.3.0
libbson bundled version => 1.8.0
libmongoc bundled version => 1.8.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, of course, there's something missing!

Right after posting this I noticed that I completely forgot to declare the version of `mongodb/mongodb` inside `composer.json`, so composer was downloading always the latest version of the library, which is `1.3.0`.

`mongodb/mongodb` also deprecated support to `2.4` in their [1.3.0 release](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/releases).

I was able to fix the issue by locking the version of `mongodb\mongodb` to `1.2.0` in `composer.json`:

`"mongodb/mongodb": "1.2.0"`

Hope this helps someone that might be facing the same issue.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the mongo db extension is installed and available.
Install it with pecl:

```
// Old version
sudo pecl install mongo

// New version
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

You should add "extension=mongodb.so" to php.ini

Comment: Thank you @llioor, the extension was correctly installed and the problem was due to lack of version locking in the composer file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48808091/1891542