# Call to undefined method MongoDB::update()

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

when using the `update` statement via `PHP` means am getting the error.

> Call to undefined method MongoDB::update()

I'm using the `mongo-php-driver` driver for connecting the `MongoDB` and `PHP`

My Code

```
$result = $this->mongo_db->update('table_name',array('user_type'=>"D"),array('$set'=>array('account_balance'=>0)),array('upsert'=>true));
```

My MongoDB reference link is https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: I'm assuming `$this->mongo_db` is a handle to the Mongo connection. `update` would be a function on the *collection*, not the Mongo connection.

Comment: `$this->mongo_db` this is from my php constructor bro, `insertOne` and `updateOne` statements are working fine for me. But the bulk update is not working @ChrisWhite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi am using `updateMany` instead of `update`. Its working fine for me.

```
$result = $this->mongo_db->updateMany('table_name',array('user_type'=>"D"),array('$set'=>array('account_balance'=>0)),array('upsert'=>true));
```

Answer (score 0):

### From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.2/tutorial/crud/#update-documents)

> Use the `MongoDB\Collection::updateOne()` method to update a single document matching a filter. `MongoDB\Collection::updateOne()` returns a `MongoDB\UpdateResult` object, which you can use to access statistics about the update operation.

```
<?php

$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->test->users;
$collection->drop();

$collection->insertOne(['name' => 'Bob', 'state' => 'ny']);
$collection->insertOne(['name' => 'Alice', 'state' => 'ny']);
$updateResult = $collection->updateOne(
    ['state' => 'ny'],
    ['$set' => ['country' => 'us']]
);

printf("Matched %d document(s)\n", $updateResult->getMatchedCount());
printf("Modified %d document(s)\n", $updateResult->getModifiedCount());
```

### For Extra Read:

> The MongoDB PHP Library and underlying [mongodb extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) have notable API differences from the [legacy mongo extension](https://www.php.net/mongo). Please read the [upgrade guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.1/upgrade/) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

You should check if the mongo db extension is installed and available. Install it with pecl:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74844843/2862728